# View/undo a Hg commit?

Tags: mercurial, commit, pull

- How do I view commits that are about to be pushed?
- I'd made a local commit. Pull a change. And no it requires a merge.
  I prefer not to merge and would like to undo the commit,
  Pull,
  Update changes,
  Then commit again.

How do I do it since `rollback` only undo the last command which is pull?

Comment: @pst, that's not true.  `hg rollback` (a **very** dangerous command) undoes the last command that modified the repository, be it a `commit`, a `pull`, or a etc.

Comment: @Ry4an thanks. understand that. was explaining in my in scenario :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> - How do I view commits that are about to be pushed?

Use `hg outgoing`. That shows what `hg push` would have sent to the server. The opposite command is `hg incoming`, which shows what `hg pull` would have retrieved.

> - I'd made a local commit. Pull a change. And no it requires a merge. I prefer not to merge and would like to undo the commit, Pull, Update changes, Then commit again.

Like Mark says, you're looking for the [rebase extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/RebaseExtension#A_common_case). Enable it with

```
[extensions]
rebase =
```

in your config file and then run

```
$ hg pull
$ hg rebase
```

to move your local work (this can be multiple changesets, not just a single as in your work around!) on top of the changesets you just pulled down.

> How do I do it since rollback only undo the last command which is pull?

**Please** don't use `hg rollback` as a general undo mechanism. It's a low-level command that should not be used as much as it is, especially not by new users. The rollback command removes the last *transaction* from the repository — a transaction in Mercurial is typically the last changeset you made *or* the last changesets (plural) you pulled into the repository.

Comment: What is the recommended command to undo a mistake in preference of rollback then?

Comment: @resting: Like Mark and I wrote, you can use the rebase extension to move a committed change "on top" of the changesets you've pulled down. But don't think of committing before pulling as a **mistake**! It's perfectly normal behavior in all DVCS to commit locally, pull, and then merge. That should be your **default** until you understand why and when rebase can help you.

Answer (score 4):

That's really the way Mercurial works, and you shouldnt fight it in the name of a straight linear history, but there are tools that can edit history.  Enable the `rebase` extension and just run `hg rebase` after your pull. It will move your local commit to the tip automatically in the simple case you described.

Comment: is exactly right here.  A DVCS that looks like a braid is a mark of a DVCS  user that understands and embraces his or her tools' strengths.  Merging _is_ coding, and skipping it is falsifying history.

Comment: I see...if I'm not wrong git was able to 'uncommit' with `reset` and move all changes back to its modified state. That allows a pull and avoids an unnecessary merge (in my opinion since my commits could just go on top of the pulled changes). Makes the history cleaner.

Comment: Cleaner, but inaccurate.  A merge still happened...it is just hidden.

Comment: @resting: Yes, you can get a more straight-line history that way. The rebase extension allows you to obtain the same straight-line history in Mercurial. The same in Git, for that matter: it's also not recommended to `git reset` before every `git pull`. Instead you `git commit` (as much as you want!) and then `git rebase -i` later, if you like.

Comment: hmm...alright. i'll get myself familiar into this flow of rebasing. thanks :)